# Meldeversäumnisse Bedeutung

Tags: meaning

Ich habe im [Duden](https://www.duden.de) das Wort gesucht. Keine Ergebnisse wurde gezeigt. Was bedeutet *Meldeversäumnisse*?

Comment: Es ist ein aus _melden_ und _Versäumnis_ zusammengesetztes Wort. Vielleicht hilft das ja schon, um die Bedeutung zu ergründen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Versäumnis* means to have not done something which should have been done. *Melden* means to report or to notify.

So *Meldeversäumnis* means something like *failure to report*. It is a bureaucratic  term and may for instance be used when people don't show up for scheduled appointments or fail to notify the employment agency of something.

Comment: I am pretty sure, _Meldeversäumnis_ relates more specific to _Anmeldung einer Wohnung_.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: While this would also have been my guess,  it is apparently wrong, see [§ 32 SGB II Meldeversäumnisse - arbeitsagentur.de](https://www.arbeitsagentur.de/datei/FW-SGB-II-32_ba015867.pdf) indicates a topic related to agency for work.

Comment: @guidot Thank you! Learned something new.